# Can I reuse Mongoose Schema Models in other projects and keep them synchronized?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am building an ecommerce website that's pretty much standard. The problem is that it also has an administrator portal to be used by company employees. I have decided to deploy two different front end applications using Angular 8 but I am doubtful whether to use a single blackened "project" or two. In order to save on resources I have decided to split it in two so my customer api doesn't have to load the employee stuff and vice versa. My question is, how can I keep the Mongoose Schema Models synchronized in these two separate projects? Is this a good idea/practice at all? Should I just keep it all together? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer this question instead.

> In order to save on resources I have decided to split it in two so my customer api doesn't have to load the employee stuff and vice versa.

1. Have you determined that the resources loaded will be significant enough to warrant this optimization. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Programmer time is the most expensive time.
2. If you need the two apis to be separate, you can simply have /customer and /employee routes. No need to have two backend servers.
3. if you need to load only specific fields, mongoose allows [Model.find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) to include specific fields via projection.
4. You can add methods to the model to help you add additional queries. For example, findByIdAsEmployee to add a projection to limit fields for employee consumption. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html
5. If you absolutely have to, you can use 2 models from the same schema in the same backend.

2 backends are generally more trouble than they are worth. Even if the volume is very high, it's easier to load balance with more identical instances. You only want to split the project when you know the overhead is very expensive. In this case, extra code and extra routes are basically free.